# Gulp task to create a .sql file from a MySQL Database

Tags: mysql, wordpress, git, gulp

I want to create an automated `gulp` task to create a `.sql` file from my database.

I am currently working across several machines with a `WordPress` website, and need to ensure that the database stays consistent across the multiple machines.

My plan is to add a `.sql` file to the `git` repository and use Gulp to update the file whenever anything in the database changes.

I understand that it's not necessarily best practice to commit a `.sql` file (or most of `WordPress`) to a `git` repository, but in my current situation, I do not have  a choice.

Are there any `gulp` tools I can use to create this task?

Comment: This sounds like a potential maintenance nightmare. You should really look into mysql replication https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication.html

Comment: Development across all the machines is local, and there is no server currently setup with a MySQL database. Would this still be achievable?

Comment: Ah no, I misunderstood your use case. When you say there is no mysql server setup do you mean independent of your local machines?

Comment: Ah yes, sorry. I meant there are no live servers, everything is done locally and independently per machine

Comment: Also, the solution to this problem does not have to be solved with gulp specifically, but I would need some form of automatic solution